# Displaying Blob value in PrimeFaces datatable?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jsf-2, hql

Am developing a web application using **jsf** as front-end and **hibernate** as back-end. Am storing some paragraph in my **mysql** database in **BLOB datatype** . I want to display the paragraph line in jsf data table. If I retrieve the blob value from  database means it displayed as object. How can I retrieve as a paragraph text.

Comment: I believe its binary, so you need to know what format it's saved in

Comment: @jaquen H'ghar  ya...i saved it as byte[] array...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saved blob value as byte[] array. While retrieving the valuse from mysql datatbase i displayd as it is. so it displayed as binary. Finally i convert byte to String like below i mentioned.

```
String example = "Sample String";
byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();
String s=new String(bytes);
```

Comment: @kark upvote pannitu doubt ah? Tell me what is tour doubt? I will solve your doubt.

Comment: how to compare two..in notepad++ ...u do some shortcuts know...what is that...or we need any plugin for that..

Comment: when ur free come to **kark-apesk** chat room..in stackoverflow

Comment: yes..compare plugin is available for this da..download and load it in to plugin folder.. short cut is alt+D..